# Wire gauge for sensor at long distance

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, soil-sensing

I am planning for a home irrigation system and confused with the wire gauge required the sensors on the plants.

The circuit diagram would be something like below: (Please consider the sensors as Capacitive Soil Moisture sensor instead of IR sensor as displayed).

[image]

Now, considering the final sensor being at a maximum distance of 5 meters from NodeMcu and Power supply, what should be the consideration for wire gauge for both the 5V power supply and data signals? Also, do I need to use voltage logic level shifter?

Comment: Do you understand the considerations behind the gauge choice? You should estimate the current in these wires, then the resulting voltage drop. Then you compare the resulting voltage with the acceptable levels. There are also heat dissipation considerations, but these are not very relevant for in your case.

Comment: Yes @EugeneSh., I am trying understand the voltage drop across the wire. I am trying one of the online tools to calculate the same, this is what I get: 

Wire Type: Copper
Wire Dia: 3mm
Voltage: 5V
Amps: 10A
Distance: 5 meters

Expected Voltage Drop: 0.24 V

Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: 10A current does not seem correct at all.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneSh., I understand now its not the apms of the power supply but the power draw which should not exceed 0.1 Amps

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: I’m fixing this because I realized I put incorrect information in this answer

> what should be the consideration for wire gauge for both the 5V power supply and data signals?

These types of sensors use pretty low currents, so you shouldn’t expect much of a voltage drop on the power or signal wires regardless of wire gauge. I typically like using 26 AWG or larger just because it’s easier to handle than smaller gauges.

> Also, do I need to use voltage logic level shifter?

Your manufacturer should have information on the output voltage levels of the sensor. If it’s less than the maximum input voltage of your ADC then you do not need to translate the voltage. If it is greater than the maximum input voltage of the ADC, you should use a voltage divider to step it down instead of a level shifter. Level shifters are for translating digital logic levels, but this is an analog signal.

Answer (score 1):

18-gauge is a relative standard size for direct burial for sprinkler applications.

I would not expect your circuit to operate properly or reliably. I am making the same assumption about the multiplexer as there is no technical information on anything.  The nodeMCU  or multiplexer were not designed to have long wires connected to there pins. These long wires will bring in electrical noise and transients that can destroy your computer or at least cause it to malfunction.

You need to add an interface to make the levels compatable to your multiplexer input. The input voltage range for the ADC pin on the micro is 0–1.0V while reading external voltage, multiplexer unknown. Since these are analog signals you will need a resistor divider instead of a digital level converter.

You need protection on all of your analog inputs. This can be accomplished by using a resistor divider and then adding something in the 10K range from the output of the divider to the analog input.

Your relay has no flyback protection. The NodeMCU was not designed to drive relays or anything inductive. Also it cannot supply the necessary current. You can use a MOSFET or transistor to drive the relay or get one of the relays that already contain a driver, very popular with the Arduino crowd. Note the output is 3.3V.

Vin is good for the 5V as you will get additional filtering form the onboard power supply. You can also have problems with the 5 meter wire on the 5 Volt feed.

Hopefully this helps you get started. I am fairly it is not the answer you want but I also believe you want it to operate reliably for a long time, this will get you started on that path. It is always a good idea to post links to technical information for hardware links, many have the same name but are different.

Answer (score 0):

28 gauge. No specific reason, I have a lot in my disposal, sensor will not take any serious current, too thin wires are hard to handle. There are shielded & twisted 3 wires in a jacket, that is preferred for low level signals.

Comment: Thank you @jay. Any other consideration I would need to make?

Comment: @AvirupDas go ahead and try. There is no single way to do wiring. And, you will find your own solutions and issues with your approach, that looks reasonable for me to begin with.